# tplquad: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to run this code but I get the error in the title. I looked for the documentation and examples about tplquad, but I couldn't understand my problem. Thank you very much in advance!

here my code:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad,dblquad,tplquad
from scipy.integrate import nquad

fig_width = 6.
fig_height = fig_width*0.75
fig_size =  [fig_width,fig_height]
params = {'backend': 'TkAgg',
          'axes.labelsize': 30,
          'text.fontsize': 20,
          'title.fontsize': 20,
          'legend.fontsize': 20,
          'xtick.labelsize': 20,
          'ytick.labelsize': 20,
          'text.usetex': False,
          'font.family': 'sans-serif',
          'figure.figsize': fig_size}
rcParams.update(params)

pi=3.14
pt_T=3.
#T=0.47
thetaP= -pi
precision=5
y=0


M_T=linspace(1.,7.,precision)
integral1d=[0]*precision


#chi now is def with a plus instead of the minus in the article
def chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T):
    return abs((2*p1*T*sqrt(pt_T**2+(M_T**2+pt_T**2)*sinh(y)**2)*sin(thetaP)*sin(thetap1))**2 - (2*p1*T*(sqrt(M_T**2+pt_T**2)*cosh(y)- sqrt(pt_T**2+(M_T**2+pt_T**2)*sinh(y)**2)*cos(thetaP) *cos(thetap1) )-(T**2)* M_T**2)**2)+1

def p1max(thetaP, thetap1,T,M_T):
    return (M_T**2)*T/(2*(sqrt(M_T**2+pt_T**2)*cosh(y)- sqrt(pt_T**2+(M_T**2+pt_T**2))*sinh(y)**2*cos(thetaP-thetap1)))-0.1

def p1min(thetaP, thetap1,T,M_T):
    #NOT SURE ABOUT THE T AT DENOMINATOR
    return (M_T**2)*T/(2*(sqrt(M_T**2+pt_T**2)*cosh(y)- sqrt(pt_T**2+(M_T**2+pt_T**2))*sinh(y)**2*cos(thetaP+thetap1))) +0.1

def integral(thetaP,T,M_T): 
    area =dblquad(lambda p1, thetap1: 5*(1/(18*pi**5))*sin(thetap1)*(p1/(sqrt(chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T))))*(1/(exp(p1/T) + 1))*(1/(exp((sqrt(M_T**2 + pt_T**2)*cosh(y) - p1/T) +1))) , -pi+0.1, -0.1, lambda p1: p1min(thetaP, p1,T,M_T), lambda p1: p1max(thetaP,p1,T,M_T))  #CHANGE   1., lambda p1:10.)
    return area[0]

def integrand(M_T, p1,thetap1,T):
    return pt_T*T*2*pi*5*(1/(18*pi**5))*sin(thetap1)*(p1/(sqrt(chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T))))*(1/(exp(p1/T) + 1))*(1/(exp((sqrt(M_T**2 + pt_T**2)*cosh(y) - p1/T) +1)))


def formula151(M_T):
    area =tplquad(lambda  p1, thetap1,T:  pt_T*T*2*pi*5*(1/(18*pi**5))*sin(thetap1)*(p1/(sqrt(chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T))))*(1/(exp(p1/T) + 1))*(1/(exp((sqrt(M_T**2 + pt_T**2)*cosh(y) - p1/T) +1))) ,0.333, 20./3,lambda thetap1: -pi+0.1, -0.1, lambda thetap1, p1: p1min(thetaP, p1,T,M_T),lambda thetap1,p1: p1max(thetaP,p1,T,M_T) ) 
    return area[0]


#solving the integral
for ind in range(0, precision):
    integral1d[ind]=formula151( M_T[ind])
    print integral1d[ind]



plot(M_T,integral1d)
xlabel('M/T')
ylabel('prod rate')
title('thetaP =-3.12')
plt.yscale('log')
#plt.xscale('log')
show()
```

the error comes from line 57, where tplquad is used, and the full traceback is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/chiara/Scrivania/formula15a.py in <module>()
     61 #solving the integral
     62 for ind in range(0, precision):
---> 63         integral1d[ind]=formula151( M_T[ind])
     64         print integral1d[ind]
     65 

/home/chiara/Scrivania/formula15a.py in formula151(M_T)
     55 
     56 def formula151(M_T):
---> 57         area =tplquad(lambda  p1, thetap1,T:  pt_T*T*2*pi*5*(1/(18*pi**5))*sin(thetap1)*(p1/(sqrt(chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T))))*(1/(exp(p1/T) + 1))*(1/(exp((sqrt(M_T**2 + pt_T**2)*cosh(y) - p1/T) +1))) ,0.333, 20./3,lambda thetap1: -pi+0.1, -0.1, lambda thetap1, p1: p1min(thetaP, p1,T,M_T),lambda thetap1,p1: p1max(thetaP,p1,T,M_T) )
     58         return area[0]
     59 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in tplquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, qfun, rfun, args, epsabs, epsrel)
    498 
    499     """
--> 500     return dblquad(_infunc2,a,b,gfun,hfun,(func,qfun,rfun,args),epsabs=epsabs,epsrel=epsrel)
    501 
    502 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args, epsabs, epsrel)
    433 
    434     """
--> 435     return quad(_infunc,a,b,(func,gfun,hfun,args),epsabs=epsabs,epsrel=epsrel)
    436 
    437 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    252         args = (args,)
    253     if (weight is None):
--> 254         retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
    255     else:
    256         retval = _quad_weight(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limlst,limit,maxp1,weight,wvar,wopts)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    317     if points is None:
    318         if infbounds == 0:
--> 319             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    320         else:
    321             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _infunc(x, func, gfun, hfun, more_args)
    379 def _infunc(x,func,gfun,hfun,more_args):
    380     a = gfun(x)
--> 381     b = hfun(x)
    382     myargs = (x,) + more_args
    383     return quad(func,a,b,args=myargs)[0]

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

NOTE: the functions "integral" and "integrand" are defined but finally not used...I just left them there

Comment: which line contains the error ? can you show the full `Traceback`

Comment: sorry...I edited the question with the error line and the traceback!

Comment: @MarkDickinson I just tried what you suggest, but then I get this error: 
TypeError: tplquad() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)

Comment: @ChiaraGastaldi: Yes, sorry; my comment was wrong.  (I misunderstood the tplquad docs.)

Comment: You do seem to be missing an argument to `tplquad`, though:  from the docs, it looks to me as though there should be an integrand, two scalar limits and four limits in function form.  I only see three limits in functional form in your call.  It looks as though either `gfun` or `hfun` is missing.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  Your `hfun` is a scalar: `-0.1`.  That won't work - it has to be a function: `lambda thetap1: -0.1`.

Comment: what is T supposed too be in `lambda thetap1, p1: p1min(thetaP, p1, T, M_T)`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be stuffing all these callbacks and giant expressions into one line. Try breaking up these huge expressions into meaningful parts and defining temporary variables for the parts; it'll make things easier to read and debug.

Comment: Do you *really* want `pi` to be `3.14`?  You've already imported a much better approximation, three times!  (Once from each of `math`, `numpy` and `pylab`, though the `pylab` object for `pi` is the same object as the `numpy` one.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right about pi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `scipy.integrate` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html), the signature of `tplquad` (which computes a numerical approximation to a triple integral) is:

> scipy.integrate.tplquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, qfun, rfun, args=(), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)

where `func` is the function of three variables to be integrated, `a` and `b` are floating-point limits for the outer integral, `gfun` and `hfun` are functions of one variable giving the limits of the middle integral, and `qfun` and `rfun` are functions of two variables giving the limits of the innermost integral.

I had a hard time working out what was going on until I reformatted your code to be a bit more readable.  Here's your call to `tplquad`, reformatted to make the line lengths a bit shorter:

```
area = tplquad(
    lambda p1, thetap1, T: (
        pt_T*T*2*pi*5*(1/(18*pi**5))*sin(thetap1)*
        (p1/(sqrt(chi(thetap1,p1,thetaP,T,M_T))))*
        (1/(exp(p1/T) + 1))*
        (1/(exp((sqrt(M_T**2 + pt_T**2)*cosh(y) - p1/T) + 1)))
    ),
    0.333,  # a
    20./3,  # b
    lambda thetap1: -pi + 0.1,  # gfun
    -0.1,                       # hfun
    lambda thetap1, p1: p1min(thetaP, p1, T, M_T),  # qfun
    lambda thetap1, p1: p1max(thetaP, p1, T, M_T),  # rfun
)
```

(As @user2357112 suggested, it would also aid readability to pull these `lambda` expressions out of the call and define them as separate functions.  In particular, if you define a separate function for the integrand you'll be able to perform the computation piece by piece, and won't need to put one enormous expression onto one line.)

After the reformatting, it's much easier to see what the issue is: in your call to `tplquad`, you're passing the constant `-0.1` for `hfun`.  That won't work: in mathematics, one can (ab)use a constant value to represent a constant function, but programming languages (and some mathematicians, come to that) tend to be a bit more picky: you're going to need an actual function here.  Replace `-0.1` with `lambda thetap1: -0.1`.

By the way, I'm also a bit suspicious of your variable orders here.  The doc page says that while the order of inputs for the integrand should be `(z, y, x)`, `gfun` and `hfun` should be functions of just `x`, and `qfun` and `rfun` should be functions of `(x, y)` (in that order).  That doesn't seem to match what you have.